# How to change Gmail settings to automatically unhide pictures in messages

Tags: settings, gmail

Among the settings of recent versions of Gmail there is the following entry:

> **Hide pictures in messages**
>
> Until you allow by sender, pictures won’t display automatically

Tapping the entry brings this dialog:

> Hide pictures in messages?
>
> Cancel  OK

How do I change this setting so that Gmail automatically displays pictures in messages? I’m aware that it’s possible to display pictures on a message by message or sender by sender basis. Here I’m referring to reversing the effect of tapping *OK* in the above dialog. Tapping *Cancel* only dismisses the dialog without changing the setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what version of Gmail you have, but the version I have (along with Android 4.1.2) allows me to "Show Pictures" in the message, then I have the option to "Always show pictures from this sender".

[image: Always show pictures from this sender]

The option in the settings is to "Remove" the always show that you have set for any sender in the past.

The only way to always show images is by first showing them for a sender, then select the always show. And AFAIK, this can only be done per sender.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the update. and update again. It worked for me.